# cannot find module beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm beginner in python and got a project, where **BeautifulSoup is required**.
In the code its referenced like this:

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Although I installed BeeatifulSoup with PyCharm, **I'm getting this error**:

```
 ImportError: No module named bs4
```

When I change it to:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
```

I'm getting this error, where a BeautifulSoup object is used:

```
links = soupObject.find_all("a")
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

And when I simply change to:

```
 import BeautifulSoup
```

Im getting this error:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(param)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I really don't know why this code is not working on my machine?
**How could I fix it?** Thanks

Comment: Are you using BeautifulSoup4 or BeautifulSoup3?

Comment: When you're searching for available packages in PyCharm to install into your environment, and you lookup `beautifulsoup` be sure to install `beautifulsoup4` and not `BeautifulSoup` if your requirement is to use v4+.

Comment: I only found 3 in PyCharm, could this be the problem? Thanks for your help @KevinGuan

Comment: @JohnSmith Yes, this is the problem. `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` means `from beautifulsoup4...`. However, use Beautifulsoup4 is a good idea.

Comment: Download the `beautifulsoup4-4.4.1.tar.gz` file from [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/4.4/) and use `python setup.py install` to install it.

Comment: @ChristianWitts could you please write an answer so that I can rate it as correct?

Comment: I have done so @JohnSmith.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're searching for available packages in PyCharm to install into your environment, and you lookup `beautifulsoup` be sure to install `beautifulsoup4` and not `BeautifulSoup` if your requirement is to use v4+.